# How do I prove that an injective mapping is isometry?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k\leq n$, $L: \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an injective linear mapping. So $\dim(L(\mathbb{R}^k)) = k$.
But I don't know why there exists a linear isometry $Q$ such that $Q(\mathbb{R}^k) = L(\mathbb{R}^k)$
(this is a part of a proof)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint, if dim$(L(\mathbb{R}^{k}))=k$ then $L(\mathbb{R}^{k})$ has an orthonormal basis $\{x_{1},...,x_{k}\}$.

Comment: I think I get it, thank you.